# Two way lookup of id vs name ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a hash in which `id` is the key and `name` is the value. Both `id and value are unique`.

Something like this:

```
h[1] = "ABC"
h[3] = "DEF"
```

So, if I am given the key of 1, I can easily return a value "ABC".

I need to do a `reverse lookup` as well, which means if I am given a value of "DEF", I should return 3.

Also, instead of a single value or single key to do the lookup,  
I may be provided with an array of values or array of keys instead.

Should I implement two hashes, one for each, or is there any other way in ruby or rails to achieve that?

**Edit:** This question is **not related to finding a key by its value** in a hash. It is related to doing a two way lookup not in O(n) time with a better method other than creating two separate hashes.

Comment: If your hashes are big and you need both lookups to be fast and you'll be doing a lot of them, create two hashes.

Comment: Only 400 total entries

Comment: @SebastianPalma, I explained in the edit why my question is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Hash#invert](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-invert) as below,

```
reversed_h = h.invert

reversed_h['DEF']
# => 3
```

Comment: It is creating a new hash internally.

Comment: @Bhawan Yes, if your 'reverse lookup' is getting used no. of times then you should prefer to use this solution which will initially take time to reverse & later you can search many keys by value.

Comment: I need to do the reverse lookup the same number of times as the forward one. So, I am accepting this answer as the best one.

Comment: `h.values_at(*ar_of_keys)` for getting multiple values

Answer (score 3):

You can get your key this way:
`hash.key(value) => key`
[Hash#key](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-key)

```
h = { 1 => 'ABC', 3 => 'DEF' }
puts h.key('DEF')
#=> 3
```

Comment: What about the complexity?

Comment: @Bhawan: it's exactly what you think it'd be :) Definitely no O(1) here.

Comment: > I may be provided with an array of values or array of keys instead.
Solution is depend on what you have to find in this case

Comment: @Bhawan If your search by value, is single time then this is most preffered way.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, it is less than O(n) ?

Comment: @Bhawan: no, it's not. How can it?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, I agree. My bad.